# htaccess re-write rule fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect urls that are writen without `http://www`  to the full url/domain..I also try to lowercase all the letters..but I have a bug that doesnt work..please help:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
#RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going the wrong way around. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```